# What are the scenarios in which we need to use dependency property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

We can achieve the binding by simply CLR property, so why do we need to use DP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347135/demystifying-dependency-properties

Answer (score 1):

When do you need `DP`s over `CLRP`s?

- When you need `binding`
- when you need `property value change callback` (Default Implementation)
- When you need `property value validation`
- When you need `animation`
- When you need `property value inheritance`
- When you need to `attach a property value` to another element (Attached Property, but still)
- When you need `styling`

Some of these can be implemented in `CLR` properties. But, with `DP`s, its piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

Typically these are declared in `UserControl`s and derived controls.

You can bind **to** a CLR property, but you can't bind **with** a CLR property; you'll need a dependency property to do any binding.

#### Edit (in response to comment)

Let's say you need a TextBox, but you want to customize it to have different behaviour in "EditMode" and "ReadMode". You'll need to either create a derived class or a `UserControl`; in either case you'll add a DependencyPropery.

```
public class TextBoxWithModes : TextBox
{
    public bool EditMode
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(EditModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditModeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EditMode", typeof (bool), typeof (TextBoxWithModes));
}
```

With this in place, you can declare it in XAML:

```
<Namespace:TextBoxWithModes Text="enter text here"
    Width="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    EditMode="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=editModeCheckBox}" />
```

Comment: please give me an example for more clarity.